# How (i.e. with what instruments) can one measure electric flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, measurements

Supposing we have a charge distribution and some curve $C$ bounding a surface $S$, how does one measure the electric flux through $S$ with practical equipment/instrumentation?

Does one use a voltmeter to measure the charge induced in the surface of a wire or plate and then use equations to determine the flux?

Comment: Electric flux from what?

Comment: Why is this being down-voted? The OP obviously doesn't speak English as a first language, but the question itself is actually rather straightforward and interesting.

Comment: @ DanielSank, Thanks for your understanding and edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two classes of methods one could practicably use.

**1. Method grounded on Ampère's law**

If your flux is time-varying, then, in air or dielectric (no conductivity), Ampère's law will give you the time derivative of the electric displacement flux through your loop (call it $\Gamma$):

$$\oint_\Gamma \vec{H}\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec{\ell}=\epsilon\;\mathrm{d}_t\Phi_E(t)\tag{1}$$

so you could position an array of Hall-effect sensors around the loop and calculate the integral on the left of (1) from their measurement. You only need to position the Hall sensor to measure the component of $\vec{H}$ tangential to the loop. This works especially well if your fields are zero mean and sinusoidally varying with time: these are easy to integrate reliably to find $\Phi_E(t)$ from its time derivative. Otherwise, you will need to build a predominantly integrating state estimator to track the $\Phi_E(t)$ and calibrate it from time to time with a $\Phi_E$ value measured by some other means.

**2. Direct Electric Field Measurement**

The other class of measurements are essentially what your last line says: we sample the electric field at points within the loop using essentially a voltmeter over a length, or at least some measurement of $\vec{E}$ through its tendency to shift charge. There are a dizzying number of ways to do this, from the simple voltmeter across a length to optical measurement through the many [Electro-optical effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro-optic_effect) that electric fields have on optical fiber and other optical sensors.